# Rename Wildcard File in Visual Basic Script

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

New user here.  I've been searching high and low for what I would think is a relatively simple task.  I want to rename a file with a wildcard (i.e. FileNamexxx.xls) within a Visual Basic Script.  I'll be running this script within Visual Studio.

Any help is much appreciated.

I will only have 1 file in this folder, so I do not believe a loop is necessary.
Actual FileName is "CellModelHistory1251234.xls"

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime

<Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute()> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim OldName As String
        Dim NewName As String
        OldName = Dir("X:\Database Build\SQL Downloads\Temp\CellModel*.xls")
        NewName = Dir("X:\Database Build\SQL Downloads\Temp\CellModelHistory.xls")
        FileSystem.Rename(OldName, NewName)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Upon execution, I receive the following errors:
DTS Script Task: Runtime Error
DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code:
Project name: ST_87aa37cb3ec4469d9eca36223aae33ee
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTATaskScriptingEngine.ExecuteScript()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this your complete code?  `FileSystem` has not been instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

You may as well check there really is only one .xls file in the directory, and you can use methods from System.IO to do everything:

```
Dim srcDir As String = "X:\Database Build\SQL Downloads\Temp"
Dim files = IO.Directory.GetFiles(srcDir, "*.xls")
If files.Count = 1 Then
    Dim destFile = IO.Path.Combine(srcDir, "CellModelHistory.xls")
    IO.File.Move(files(0), destFile)
Else
    Throw New Exception("No .xls or more than one .xls file in " & srcDir)
End If
```

Comment: Andrew part of my SSIS process will be to move this file to a different folder after this rename is complete.  The following day a new file will be brought in.

That being said, it may make sense to implement a multi-file identifier.  thank you.

Comment: Andrew i used this and receive the exact same error as i posted above...any ideas?  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Ah, it looks like the actual error messages are missing from your post: the lines all start "at..." when there should be an error message there somewhere. I take it the account running your program has read and write access to the directory with the .xls file in?

Comment: yes it has R/W access - i added in the rest of the Runtime Error above

Comment: If X: is a mapped drive, try using a UNC path. The account the SSIS process runs under may not have that mapping. If only the error message had a useful description. Failing that, wrap the code in a Try..Catch block and write the exception message to a local directory to which everyone has full access.